# Style field modification from .cs code

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a style described in Grid.resources. How could I modify height and width(in my sample they are 20 and 20) of Ellipse from Thumb? Other properties are accessible from other parts of code but not this((

```
<Style x:Key="CustomThumbForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="3" Height="20" Width="20"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not modify templates, if anything you use a [`TemplateBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) to make properties settable on the control that is being templated. (Also you do not modify a style either)

*(If you need to retain the defaults you can use a `Setter` to set the properties bound via the `TemplateBinding`)*

Comment: could you post a link on something with example?

Comment: @PapaJohn: There *is* a link already? Also there's the [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatebindingextension.aspx) which also linked in the other link.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Style` from the code behind using the [`FindResource(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) method on the `FrameworkElement` that contains the `Style`. If you cast the result of the method to `Style` then you can access it's `Setters`.

Alternately, change the `Width` and `Height` properties to read from a `Resource` or `Binding` and then modify that.